# Laravel route got confuse about id and slug

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have a route in my project like below :

```
    Route::get('/product/{category}/{all}/{name}-{id}.html', ['as' => 'product.single', 'uses' => 'ProductController@single'])->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

so here is the problem , as a tradition we put slug in url( and then id after that ) , but this way some of our routes will get confuse in id section, here is a example :
 /product/gold/women-gold/one-special-167.html
because of ((-)) in the url laravel think special-167 is the id although it's not.
so is there any reasonable way to get around this problem?

Comment: Why don't use route like /{name}/{id}.html

Comment: like special/167 then you can pick your id very easily

Comment: @AmitGupta because the url pattern is not suppose to be like that (in my case of course)

Comment: then you can separate name with id in your controller itself then pass them to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the **{id}** first (and then **{name}**) in your route and in your method at the same time:

```
Route::get('/product/{category}/{all}/**{id}**-**{name}**.html', ['as' => 'product.single', 'uses' => 'ProductController@single'])->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily replace id and name in the route or devide them /

Answer (score 0):

Please try enable - character for name

```
 Route::get('/product/{category}/{all}/{name}-{id}.html', ['as' => 'product.single', 'uses' => 'ProductController@single'])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+','name' => '[a-zA-Z-]+']);
```